# App layout messed up after updating to newest iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

Background: My company has support contracts for an app to always make it work for the two latest iOS versions. Now instead of updating the deployment target and building it with the newest iOS version they just checked if the app that was built with iOS7 and a deployment target of iOS5(!!!) still worked on iPads with the newest iOS. And with some adjustments they somehow managed to make it work.

Now it's all coming back: The app won't work for iOS11, it didn't even build for arm64 till now. And I got the awesome task of making it work.

Making the app build with arm64 wasn't even that hard, just had to replace some libraries. But when building for iOS11 the layout of the app is messed up. One small example: On the login screen we got some buttons that will just cut their labels for no apparent reason. There is enough space for the text but it's still cutting off. Everything else on this view is the same as before.

The code for the buttons (Interface Builder hasn't been used in this app) looks completely fine to me, it's pretty much the same how I would do it today. So my guess is that there are some build settings or similar stuff I have to change for it to look like it should. Can anyone give me a hint here on what to do?

If you want to check out the code for the button, here you go. I can't give you all the code I have since it's company code but this should be no problem:

```
loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
loginButton.titleLabel.font = BUTTON_FONT_SMALL;
loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(x, passwordField.frame.origin.y + passwordField.frame.size.height + spacerHeight * 2, fieldLength, labelHeight);
loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

loginButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorFromString:@"47;72;127"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

[loginButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageActive forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[loginButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageActive forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

loginButton.tag = 1;
[loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(login_Tapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[self view] addSubview:loginButton];
```

Comment: the above code is fine. So it will not be identify on this. Please check you  view frame according device size. I guess your view or window frame is not right . Please check the window and view frame

Comment: So what is deployment target now? ios 8 or 5?

Comment: @Lalitkumar window is initialized with [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] so it's (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 1024, height = 768)). And the view is the view of the root controller so it should be the same. It's not changed anywhere

Comment: @Cy-4AH The new deployment target is 10.3

Comment: Are you aware of Xcode's View Debugging tool?  It can capture the display of a running app and let you look at the view hierarchy, sizes, placement, z-order....